# CSS - flexible number of columns with width determined by content - possible?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

This HTML fragment spreads a long list of short items over a series of columns so that it's easier to scan and doesn't take up as much vertical space.  Everything is neatly aligned and the number of columns automatically adjusts itself if you resize the browser window.  That's all great.  The only problem is that the *width* of each column is hardcoded in the CSS.

```
<!doctype html>
<style>
ul.hlist {
    width: 80%;
    column-width: 6em;
    -moz-column-width: 6em;
    -webkit-column-width: 6em;
}
ul.hlist > li { display: block; }
</style>
<p>This header unconditionally uses one or more of these deprecated 
   integer typedefs:</p>
<ul class="hlist">
    <li><code>caddr_t</code></li>
    <li><code>daddr_t</code></li>
    <li><code>fsid_t</code></li>
    <li><code>quad_t</code></li>
    <li><code>u_int_t</code></li>
    <li><code>u_quad_t</code></li>
    <li><code>u_int16_t</code></li>
    <li><code>u_int32_t</code></li>
    <li><code>u_int64_t</code></li>
    <li><code>u_int8_t</code></li>
    <li><code>u_char</code></li>
    <li><code>u_short</code></li>
    <li><code>u_int</code></li>
    <li><code>u_long</code></li>
    <li><code>n_short</code></li>
    <li><code>n_long</code></li>
    <li><code>n_time</code></li>
</ul>
```

With some JavaScript, one can scan the list and override `column-width` to the actual width of the widest list item; there's some fiddliness because each `<li>` is stretched to the current width of the column, so you have to look inside, but that's not a serious hurdle.

```
function innerWidth (el) {
    var kids = el.children;
    var w = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++)
        w += kids[i].offsetWidth;
    return w;
}
function setColumnWidth (list) {
    var items = list.children;
    var mW = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var w = innerWidth(items[i]);
        if (w > mW)
            mW = w;
    }
    list.setAttribute("style",
                      "column-width:" + mW + "px;" +
                      "-moz-column-width:" + mW + "px;" +
                      "-webkit-column-width:" + mW + "px");
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
    var lists = document.getElementsByClassName("hlist");
    for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++)
        setColumnWidth(lists[i]);
});
```

The *question* is, is there any way to get the same (or nearly so) effect as this JS using only CSS? Please note:

- In the example, every `<li>` has its contents wrapped in a `<code>`, but your answer must not rely on this, because it ain't necessarily so in other cases.
- I already have an entirely client-side solution, and additional server-side processing in context is extremely awkward, so I strongly prefer client-only answers.
- Answers involving experimental or not-yet-deployed-at-all CSS features are just fine.

Rendering without JS: http://jsfiddle.net/7F8n6/2/ (columns are rather too wide)
Rendering with JS: http://jsfiddle.net/7F8n6/3/

Answer (score 0):

The items are inside <code> elements so by default are rendered with a monospaced font. That means their width only depends on the number of characters.

Assuming you can influence the complete page on the server, determine the item with the most characters on the server. Here it's 9.

Now generate a CSS rule in the page that sets the column width to 9 characters:

```
column-width: 9ch;
-moz-column-width: 9ch;
-webkit-column-width: 9ch;
```

The 'ch' unit is the width of a single '0' (zero). It's not supported on every browser, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Font-relative_lengths), so I don't know if this solution is good enough for you.

Comment: Regrettably, in context, additional server-side processing is extremely awkward: I would very much prefer a client-only solution (and I *have* one right now, I just want to get rid of the JS).  Also, the `<code>` elements are not necessarily present; I probably should've left them out.